# Using generic class with constraints to query from DocumentDB

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to query an object from azure cosmos document DB. `UserRepository` is made generic so that the consumer can define its own `User` object when using the repository as long as it implements `IUser` interface.

Here is the UserRepository

```
public class UserRepository<T> : IUserRepository<T> where T : class, IUser
{
    private readonly CosmosDbOptions _cosmosDBOptions;
    private readonly DocumentDbHelper _documentDBHelper;

    public UserRepository(
        IOptions<CosmosDbOptions> cosmosDBOptions,
        DocumentDbHelper documentDBHelper)
    {
        _cosmosDBOptions = cosmosDBOptions.Value;
        _documentDBHelper = documentDBHelper;
    }

    public T GetUserByEmail(string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            return default(T);

        var user = _documentDBHelper
            .GetItemsAsync<T>(u => ((T)u).Email == email, _cosmosDBOptions.DocumentDb.UserCollection, email)
            .Result
            .OrderBy(u => u.Modified)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return user;
    }

    ...
}
```

Here is what the DocumentDbHelper looks like

```
public class DocumentDbHelper
{
    private readonly DocumentClient _client;
    private readonly DocumentDbOptions _documentDBOptions;

    public DocumentDbHelper(IOptions<CosmosDbOptions> documentDBOptions)
    {
        _cosmosDBOptions = documentDBOptions.Value.DocumentDb;

        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
        };

        _client = new DocumentClient(
            new Uri(_cosmosDBOptions.Endpoint), _cosmosDBOptions.AuthKey, serializerSettings);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string collectionId, string partitionKey)
    {
        var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_cosmosDBOptions.DatabaseId, collectionId),
            new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) })
        .Where(predicate)
        .AsDocumentQuery();

        var results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
        }

        return results;
    }

    ...
}
```

And here is how the UserRepository being used

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public UsersController(IUserRepository<User> userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Get(string email)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetUserByEmail(email);
        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

Just to clarify again, the UserRepository is made generic so that other consumer can do something like this.

```
public class Users2Controller : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserRepository<User2> _userRepository;

    public Users2Controller(IUserRepository<User2> userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Get(string email)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetUserByEmail(email);
        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

The problem is when executing `UsersController.Get` and it reaches `GetItemsAsync` of `DocumentDbHelper`, this method returns `null`, even though there is an object with a valid email address as passed to the controller action.

But when I change the constraints of UserRepository from `where T : class, IUser` to `where T : User` like below,

```
public class UserRepository<T> : IUserRepository<T> where T : User
```

the object is retrieved successfully.

Why is this? Is it possible to make this work by having the interface constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause.

Here is the snippet of `User` class:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string DocumentId { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonProperty("created")]
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("modified")]
    public DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And here is how the `IUser` interface used to look:

```
public interface IUser
{
    string DocumentId { get; set; }

    DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }

    string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The problem is related to this https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/317. Once I added `JsonProperty` attribute to the `IUser` interface props like below:

```
public interface IUser
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    string DocumentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created")]
    DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("modified")]
    DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it as mentioned below, this should work.

```
public class UserRepository<T> : IUserRepository<T> where T :  IUser
```

Comment: I've tried that, it didn't work either :) I found the problem btw. Thanks for your help